# On BigQuery, how to keep metadatas of a table, that is the destination of a scheduled query that overwrites its destination table after its running?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a scheduled request that I've configured to have a destination table and to overwrite it each time it's run.

My query retrieves and transforms all data from a data source every 4 hours. Obviously, much of the data processed is the same. However, some of the rows in my data source may have changed. Also, new rows may appear in the data source.  In order to avoid duplication and the loss of certain information, I opt for the configuration mentioned above.

However, each time the query is run, the metadata added to the destination table, such as policy tags and column descriptions, disappear. This is perfectly normal as the table is recreated each time.

I would therefore like to find a solution to keep this metadata after the query has been run.